# pytest commandline parameter rewrite

Tags: python, pytest, argparse

How can I manipulate a pytest command line option before it is being added to config object?

I like to convert a commandline parameter from csv string to an list so I can parametrize over it and do some sanity checks:

```
#### for --webhost parameter ###
def pytest_addoption(parser):
    #parser.addoption("--webhost")
    p = argparse.ArgumentParser(description="convert webhost string to array")
    p.add_argument('--webhost', help='webhost to run tests on (default: %(default)s)', default="TEST1,TEST12,TEST4,PROD")
    args, notknownargs = p.parse_known_args(sys.argv)
    if notknownargs:
        print("pytest arguments? : {}".format(notknownargs))
    sys.argv[1:] = notknownargs

    if args.webhost and isinstance(args.webhost, str):
        args.webhost = args.webhost.split(',')
    parser.addoption("--webhost", help='webhost to run tests on (default: %(default)s)', default=args.webhost)
```

My challenge is the two parser.addoption() call,
If I comment the first:

```
pytest: error: unrecognized arguments: -webhost=TEST1
```

So in order to let pytest allow the parameter I uncomment it, but then I get this on the last line:

```
ValueError: option names {'--webhost'} already added
```

There is no Parser.setoption() or similar to alter an existing option.

My workarounds are to use two variables, or setting a separate args object. I import with `from conftest import args` but then this is outside of config.

Comment: Don't you need a action='store' for the add_argument?  Also you should not need to define the add option twice. You can move the split task to pytest_runtest_setup()

Comment: What are you trying to achieve, a simple conversion of a comma-separated list to a list of strings? It's `def pytest_addoption(parser): parser.addoption('--webhost', type=lambda s: s.split(','))`, `type` argument comes from the stdlib's `argparse` ([related section in docs](https://docs.python.org/3/library/argparse.html#type)).

Comment: @eric, I'm not sure, but I believe it to be very similar to argparse, where we manipulate after parsing, but pytests like to use a config object.

Comment: https://docs.pytest.org/en/latest/_modules/_pytest/config/argparsing.html - looks like `pytest` is defining its own parsing class, one that uses `argparse`, but tries to look more like `optparse`.  With `argparse` it is possible to modify attributes such as `default` of an Action (the object returned by an `add_argument` command).  There is also a `conflict_handler` parameter that controls what happens when you  create a duplicate argument (default behavior is to raise an error).